# Chaining seq after another seq failure

Tags: bash, sequence

I have two numbers that wrap over 255, let's say 254 and 2
I want to generate a sequence of "254 255 0 1 2"

So far I've tried following methods:

```
echo $(seq 254 2 || (seq 254 255 && seq 0 2))
echo $( (seq 254 2 || seq 253 255) && seq 0 2 )
echo $(seq 254 2 || seq 254 255 && seq 0 2)
```

Which return "", "0 1 2" and "0 1 2" respectively
How can I achieve my desired result?

Comment: I'm using the resulting range inside a for (for each) loop, if it's at all relevant

Comment: I mean they COULD wrap, that's why the first seq can either fail or succeed, it's octets inside an IP address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash

```bash
myseq() {
    local mod=$1 start=$2 stop=$3
    while true; do 
        echo "$start"
        (( start == stop )) && break
        start=$(( (start + 1) % mod ))
    done
}
```

Then

```
$ myseq 256 254 2
254
255
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 1):

If stopping number is lower than starting number, add 256 to it, so that it is greater. Then just generate the numbers in the range of 256.

```
start=254
stop=2
# handle overflow
stop=$(( stop < start ? 256 + stop : stop ))
# generate the numbers
for ((i=start;i<=stop;++i)); do printf "%s\n" "$((i%256))"; done
```

Which I guess can be squeezed into some seq and awk, but I think bash above looks better anyway.

```
start=256
stop=2
seq $start $(( stop + (stop < start) * 256 )) | awk '{print $1%256}'
```

Notes: `echo $(command)` is just `command` (except word splitting). Do not execute `echo $(...)` just execute the command you want to execute. `seq 254 2 ||` it is hard to imagine for `seq` command to fail so that `||` can trigger on non-zero exit status from seq. Consider rereading some introduction to shell chaining expressions like `&&` and `||`. Overall, prefer `if` over `&&` and `if !` over `||`.

Answer (score 1):

Write a function that checks if the second number is lower than the first number

```
byteseq() {
    start=$1
    end=$2
    if ((start <= end))
    then
        seq "$start" "$end"
    else
        seq "$start" 255
        seq 0 "$end"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is perhaps easier to use gawk / perl / ruby for something like this:

Ruby:

```
seq 254 258 | ruby -lpe '$_=$_.to_i & 0xff'
```

GNU awk:

```
seq 254 258 | gawk '{print and($1, 0xff)}'
```

Or directly in Bash:

```
for i in $(seq 254 258); do
    echo $((i & 0xff))
done
```

Any of those prints:

```
254
255
0
1
2
```

You can also generate an array similarly to your attempt to use `seq` twice:

```
a=( $(seq 254 255) $(seq 0 2) ) #PURPOSELY unquoted to split
```

Test that:

```
$ declare -p a
declare -a a=([0]="254" [1]="255" [2]="0" [3]="1" [4]="2")
```

That array can now be used for a loop or whatever you were trying to generate with two calls to `seq`.